# Only allow a plugin to work on a specific page? (Prefer not to use a plugin)

Tags: plugins

I know that there is an 'answer' to my question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95140/show-plugin-only-on-a-specific-page) but it has -2 votes.

As the title of the question suggests - I am trying to allow a WordPress Plugin to ONLY execute on a template. What is the 'best' way to do this? I'd rather not use a plugin to do this and I feel comfortable to edit the functions.php file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this as [described in this blog post](https://lowgravity.pl/blog/quick-tip-how-to-disable-wp-plugin-on-certain-page/). Due to the [way WordPress loads files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622), you must use it in a [Must Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and not the theme's functions.php or a regular plugin.

I'm not the author of that blog post and don't want to copy the script from there. The idea is to add a filter to `option_active_plugins` in which you `unset()` the plugin from the array you are filtering.

Comment: Thanks....I am not thinking to use a plugin specifically for that purpose which somewhat defeats the purpose.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Using plugins to enhance WordPress is one of its core principles, also if you are doing this to reduce load time, adding a php only plugin will basically not impact your load time at all. You _could_ add custom code to the core files, but these changes will be lost after each update